# Use lodash to trigger two functions when setTimeout is executed

Tags: javascript, lodash

Is there a way to optimise this:

```
function run1 () {
  console.log("Hello");
}
function run2 () {
  console.log("World");
}
function timeoutComplete () {
  run1();
  run2();
}
setTimeout(timeoutComplete, 1000);
```

Like this, so that I don't need to declare timeoutComplete...?

```
setTimeout(_.xyz(run1, run2), 1000);
```

Comment: @Vld, I think `_.compose` is right-to-left. But `_.flow` is left-to-right, so maybe `_.flow(run1, run2)`, right?

Comment: I guess if you want left-to-right, then `flow`. I wasn't aware of it - I was going off the Underscore API - it only has `compose`.

Comment: @Vld lodash doesn't have `compose` function.

Comment: These also invokes the functions with the return value of the previous function as argument to the next, right? (Not that it matters in this specific case...)

Comment: @Vohuman my Underscore knowledge lets me down, then. Apparently, it's `flowRight` in lodash. Which is odd - I thought lodash was compatible with Underscore's API. Anyway, it's the same concept anyway, only lodash has bizarrely renamed it for some reason.

Comment: Lodash seems to have removed compose in latest version. It was available in 3.1.0. But it's known as `_.flowRight` now.

Comment: @Vld I see what you mean. – I have used both of these libraries and I prefer to use the underscore library.

Comment: I thought lodash was more widely used, so we chose that for our project. Maybe I was wrong. But lodash was branched from underscore, I think. It has most (if not all) underscore methods.

Comment: @ngDeveloper it should have all of them, I believe. You're correct that it was branched off Underscore - I believe it's due to some disagreements between the authors. At any rate, lodash is the newer one and it became bigger introducing a lot more things - it also (as far as I knew) offer full compatibility with Underscore. I don't have stats on which one is used more but Underscore does derive some of its userbase from being older. At any rate, the two can usually be used interchangeably. That `flowRight` thing is the first time I've seen a difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [delay()](https://lodash.com/docs#delay) and [flow()](https://lodash.com/docs#flow):

```
_.delay(_.flow(run1, run2), 1000);
```

The main advantage of `delay()` over `setTimeout()` is that it can pass arguments to the callback if need be.

Comment: Exactly the solution I used even before I saw your comment. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can always just use an anonymous function in the timeout and call them there:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    run1(); 
    run2();
});
```

Comment: Great answer, I must say! (Y)

Answer (score 1):

You could use an anonymous function instead:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  run1();
  run2();
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Low on disc space?  Readability of your code is superdiduper important. :)

Comment: @ngDeveloper vs the X amount of code that was used to make the same thing with a method call? Look one line: `setTimeout( function(){run1(); run2(); }, 1000);` ;)

Comment: I find it easier to read when code height is compact. Nested functions can be hard to follow.

Answer (score 0):

Write `_.xyz` yourself, except it doesn't need to be a lodash function:

```
function run(...fns) {
  return function() {
    fns.forEach(fn => fn());
  };
}

setTimeout(run(run1, run2), 1000);
```